Checking 3D Position for scenes within a group
I have a player character that constantly moves forward and can move on 3 'lanes' on the x axis, when the player switches lanes a tween handles the switch in time, however I'd like him to return to the original lane if he collides with a scene in the "Obstacle" group during the tween. I decided to handle it by checking two vectors for an Obstacle right before the tween, if there is no Obstacles the sswitch will proceed as normal, but if there is an obstacle I want to find out the first point on the x axis where the player and obstacle collide, make a tween to that point and then a tween to the player's original position on the x axis. However I'm having a hard time implementing this logic due to my lack of knowledge in godot, how can i check for a scene in a specific position?
using Godot;
using Godot.Collections;

public partial class test_character : CharacterBody3D
{

    [Export]
    public float currSpeed = 4.0f;
    [Export]
    public float maxSpeed = 16.0f;
    [Export]
    public float acceleration = 3.0f;
    public float accelerationTime = 0f;
    [Export]
    public Curve accelerationCurve;
    [Export]
    public float moveDistance = 3.0f;
    private float playerPos = 0;
    private bool isCollidingWithObstacle = false;
    public float switchDuration = 0.1f;


    public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {
        Vector3 velocity = Velocity;

        float inputDir = 0f;

        if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("move_right"))
        {
            inputDir = -1;
        }

        if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("move_left"))
        {
            inputDir = 1;
        }

        if (inputDir != 0f)
        {

            //if player presses either left or right
            if (!(playerPos == -1 && inputDir == -1) || !(playerPos == 1 && inputDir == 1))
            {
                //checks if the player can move to the left or the right

                if (playerPos == 0)
                {
                    switchLane(1, inputDir);
                }

                if ((playerPos == -1 && inputDir == 1) || (playerPos == 1 && inputDir == -1))
                {
                    switchLane(0, inputDir);
                }

            }
        }


        Vector3 direction = (Transform.Basis * new Vector3(0, 0, 1)).Normalized();

        accelerationTime += (float)delta;
        float curveValue = accelerationCurve.Sample(accelerationTime);
        currSpeed = Mathf.MoveToward(currSpeed, maxSpeed, acceleration * curveValue * (float)delta);


        velocity.Z = direction.Z * currSpeed;

        Velocity = velocity;
        MoveAndSlide();

    }

    public void switchLane(int i, float inputDir)
    {

        /*
        How i want the function to work 
        //Vector3 laneVector = new Vector3(0, GlobalPosition.Y, GlobalPosition.Z);
        //Vector3 laneVectorFront = new Vector3(GlobalPosition.X - inputDir * moveDistance, GlobalPosition.Y, GlobalPosition.Z + (currSpeed * switchDuration));

        Vector3 laneVector = new Vector3(GlobalPosition.X + inputDir * moveDistance, GlobalPosition.Y, GlobalPosition.Z);
        //laneVector - same Position as the player's current position,
        //except the X axis corresponds to the lane the player is trying to switch to

        Vector3 laneVectorFront = new Vector3(GlobalPosition.X + inputDir * moveDistance, GlobalPosition.Y, GlobalPosition.Z + (currSpeed * switchDuration));
        //laneVectorFront - same as laneVector except Z axis is bigger by (currSpeed * switchDuration)
        //which should be the vector the player should be on after the tween is succesfully finished

        if (checkForObstacle(laneVector) || checkForObstacle(laneVectorFront))
        {
            GD.Print("Obstacle detected, cant switch");
            return;
        }
        */

        //Currently the function creates a tween that switches the x axis in switchDuration amount of time
        Tween tween = GetTree().CreateTween();
        tween.SetParallel(true);
        tween.SetProcessMode(Tween.TweenProcessMode.Physics);
        playerState = _playerState.InputDisabled;
        tween.Connect("finished", new Callable(this, "switchDone"));

        if (i == 0)
        {

            tween.TweenProperty(this, "position:x", 0, switchDuration);
            playerPos = 0;

        }

        if (i == 1)
        {

            tween.TweenProperty(this, "position:x", moveDistance * inputDir, switchDuration);
            playerPos = inputDir;

        }

    }

    public void switchDone()
    {
        playerState = _playerState.Normal;
        GD.Print("lane switch finished");
    }

}


